# How can I swallow a BigQuery exception?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

New to BigQuery. I'm trying to write multiple files to BigQuery in a Python batch job. If any of the files are malformed BigQuery, as expected, throws an exception. I need to log the exception then swallow it so the next write can proceed. I've wrapped the call in try except pass but the exception still stops the job. Here's the code:

```
try:
    logging.info(f'Writing {table_name} to BigQuery. Write disposition set to {write_disposition}')

    df.to_gbq(destination_table=table_id, credentials=CREDENTIALS,
              if_exists=write_disposition)

    # Confirm the write succeeded
    table_exists = confirm_bq_table_exists(bq_client, dataset_id, table_name)
    if table_exists:
        logging.info(f'The table {table_name} was written to BigQuery')
        return True

except exceptions.BigQueryException as e:
    logging.info(f'The write attempt failed with the exception {e}')
    pass
```

Comment: It sounds like you aren't actually catching the exception. Try wrapping it in a `try, except, log to something` and confirm that you are actually catching the exception. Also, post some sample code otherwise you will get a lot of angry StackOverflow goblins coming after you.  Also, get a good IDE with a debugger and learn to step through your code so you can see for yourself what is stoping your process.

Comment: can you add try catch block code along with exception trace

Comment: Thanks Arun. I fixed the issue with the data that was breaking it so I need to create some test data that will break the BQ write. I'll do so asap

Comment: You can use try catch block. You can see this link https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp